# java- How to draw message over a Canvas?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt

I am creating a `Video Player` using `VLCJ`.

The player uses a `Canvas` as it's video surface.

```
videoPlayer.newVideoSurface(canvas);
```

So I am bounded to use `Canvas`.

I want to show message over the `Canvas` like, `"Player Started"`. I tried using a `JLayeredPane` and a `JLabel` to accomplish this.

A short-demo code:

```
package canvasexample;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class CanvasExample extends JFrame
{

public JLabel label  = new JLabel("Message");
public Canvas canvas = new MyCanvas();  
    
public CanvasExample()
{
 setSize(500, 500);
 setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 
 createWindow();
 setVisible(true);
}        
    
public void createWindow()
{
 JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
 
 JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

 panel1.setSize(500, 500);
 panel2.setSize(500, 500);
 
 label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
 
 panel1.add(canvas);
 panel2.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
 
 pane.add(panel1, 1, 0);
 pane.add(panel2, 2, 0);
 add(pane);
}        

private class MyCanvas extends Canvas  
{  
        public MyCanvas() {  
        setBackground (Color.GRAY);  
        setSize(500, 500);  
     }  
  public void paint(Graphics g)  
  {  
    g.setColor(Color.red);  
    g.fillOval(75, 75, 150, 75);  
  }  
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
 @Override
 public void run(){
   new CanvasExample();  
 }    
 });
}    
}
```

But soon I found out that you can't mix heavyweight `AWT` component and lightweight `Swing` components.

So, can anyone tell me how can I display a message over a `Canvas`?

Comment: Have you considered to use drawString method of Graphics object to accomplish your goal?

Comment: Probably related to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37602909

Comment: @AlexeiKovalev Yes, I have tried overriding `paint()` method. The thing is, it prints the string on the `Canvas` but after, `VLCJ` starts rendering the video on the `Canvas`, the string is nowhere to be found.

Comment: The answer linked by @Frakcool is exactly on-point here. Nowadays my preferred approach with vlcj is to use JavaFX and the PixelBuffer solution, it performs well, and you can overlay graphics and animations on top of it. With Canvas, you're restricted to what's described in that linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to overlay static text on an vlcj embedded canvas you need to use [Marquess](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/4.1.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/base/Marquee.html)

Or use the marque options directly in the mediaplayer [here](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.0.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/MediaPlayer.html#setMarqueeText(java.lang.String))

For overlays besides text you can have a look [AbstractJWindowOverlayComponent](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.0.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/component/overlay/AbstractJWindowOverlayComponent.html)

or I haven't tried this approach u can create an [JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) where you have your canvas at layer 1 and can have your JComponent which will draw your overlays at layer 0 with **transparent background** you can override it's paintComponent() method and draw whatever you need

Comment: Your last approach will not work. You can not overlay a light-weight `Swing` component such as `JComponent` on a heavy-weight `AWT` component such as `Canvas`.